# Losing selection background color when using getRowStyle

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using a custom `getRowStyle` handler to set the background color of rows, depending on the data for the row itself.

The problem is that it interferes with the CSS for the selected state of a row. I don't have a "selected" background color anymore.

Here's the handler:

```
getRowStyle: (params) => {

            
    let color = "white";
    let status = params.data.status;

    if (status == 0)
        color = "green";
    if (status == 1)
        color = "orange";
    if (status == 2)
        color = "lightgray";
     
    return { "background-color": color };
}
```

The flaw is obvious, but how could I respect the rule in the handler ?

Comment: you could force the removal of the css of the selected state of row. find them in the dev console and then set them to unset or any value you want.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime you can't set classes with getRowStyle.

Comment: i meant to overwrite the style of those classes that you want to remove, not remove the class itself. a brute force method, but it works with agGrid